# OpenMPI process is killed even using nohup

Tags: parallel-processing, openmpi, nohup

I'm running my program using nohup and OpenMPI:

```
nohup mpirun -np 48 -machinefile temp ./myProgram &
```

and after some hours I get this error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 18 with PID 5445 on node fenix2 exited on signal 1 (Hangup).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It occurs in random nodes at random times. I'm using the same seed for all runnings. If I run the same application in Windows with Microsoft HPC MPI then it works fine.

Do you have something that I could do in order to avoid this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Try redirecting the standard input from `/dev/null`: `nohup mpirun ... ./myProgram < /dev/null &`. Also `screen` or `tmux` are way better alternatives to running with `nohup`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I put it to run using `&` and `disown`. It looks that is working fine now. But I'll try your suggestions as soon as it finishes :)